# Close as duplicate when question asked twice by same user and answer accepted on second question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

When a user posts a question, does not receive answers that they like, posts the question again and accepts an answer on the question posted second, should any action be taken on the first question?

I tried to flag the first question as a duplicate, but the duplicate question with an accepted answer did not come up in the search for a list of duplicates.

I am assuming this is because the question was asked twice by the same user, and the question posted second is the one with the answer, so the question has not been "asked *before* and already has an answer".

Comment: you can just put the url of the second question in the dialog box. It would show up

Comment: Thanks @suraj; that worked. I was just searching by the name of the question. I did not know you could use the URL.

Comment: Can you include the URL's for it in your post here? This might have been because you chose the wrong question. I've often closed questions such as this scenario. If someone posts a question that's an exact or is very close to it, then the second one should have been closed as an exact duplicate since it constitutes as a repost, even though the first one never received an answer.

Comment: *"I tried to close the first question as a duplicate"* - You can only flag as a duplicate given your rep. Only members that bear a gold tag for the question(s) can immediately close it, or a moderator.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the original question is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223867/python-input-variable-for-my-matching-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223867/python-input-variable-for-my-matching-function), and links to the duplicate. The second time the question was asked, it was clarified and had an accepted answer. I commented requesting clarification on the first question and eventually the asker posted a link to the second question in a comment, and had already accepted an answer.

Comment: @Poosh Ah ok thanks. Yeah, it's an exact reposted code. One reason to close/flag to close which what constitutes as a repost, is to put the bug in their ear, *as it were* in order to the save behaviour over and over again but reposting the same question more than twice, to which I have seen quite a few times and a few recently. It just basically spams the system.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oops, I meant "flag", not "close". I am trying to learn to use the site better. I probably have not been helping by pretty much asking for detailed requirements on the wrong questions. The question that lead me to ask the meta about flagging appears to be a series of requests for additional features to some code to eventually have a useful program built by SO.

Comment: @Poosh No worries. I edited your post to reflect what you said in comments.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The "close as duplicate" feature does not care about the relative timing of the questions. It says "asked *before*", but that doesn't matter. It's just that, *generally*, you close a question as a duplicate of a previously-asked question. That's not a requirement. If a later question is presented more clearly, and/or has better answers, then you often want to make *that one* the "master" question and close the older one as a duplicate of it. The system allows for this.

What the "close as duplicate" system *does* normally insist upon (wrongly, in my opinion) is that the "master" question already has at least one upvoted answer. However, even this requirement is relaxed when both questions come from the same user, for precisely the scenario you describe.

If the two questions are duplicates, then one should be closed as a duplicate of the other. Simple as that. The one with the good answer(s) should be the "master", and the other one should be closed as a duplicate of it. (The redundant question should probably also be downvoted, but that's ultimately up to you.)

The duplicate search in the dialog box is not so great, in my experience. The dialog accepts URLs, though, so what you'll find is that everyone just pastes in the URL of the "master" question they want to use, either because they already knew it or because they found it using Google.